# Convert a string into an integer - each representation

Tags: c, integer

Is there a function or library that can convert *any* (default, octal, hex, ...) integer in C given as a `char[]` into an `unsigned long long int` ?

Examples:

```
1
1l
1ul
42e+10
0x2aLL
01234u
...
```

`atoi` has some problems with 0x... and the suffixes u/l.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strtoull` is about as close as it gets. This will stop at the suffix, but since you're always producing an `unsigned long long`, you don't really care about the suffix anyway. I don't believe it will work with `42e+10` either -- although the value that produces is an integer, C and C++ only define the 'e' notation for floating point numbers.

Other than that, you need/want to pass `0` as the conversion base, in which case it implements the usual C convention that a leading `0` signals octal, `0x` signals hexadecimal, and `1-9` signal decimal.

Answer (score 1):

You could use sscanf and check the return value to see if it did something useful, e.g.:

```
bool parseValue (const char *buffer, long &value)
{
if (sscanf(buffer,"%ld",&value)==1) return true;
if (sscanf(buffer,"0x%lx",&value)==1) return true;
...
return false;
}
```

You can easily add more kinds of formats to this list.
To extend this for floating point values as well, scan the buffer in a floating point value then cast or round it to the integer value, like this:

```
bool parseValue (const char *buffer, long &value)
{
if (sscanf(buffer,"%ld",&value)==1) return true;
if (sscanf(buffer,"0x%lx",&value)==1) return true;
...
double d;
if (sscanf(buffer,"%lf",&d)==1) {value=d; return true;}
...
return false;
}
```